# Are there examples of authenticating Desire2Learn api's using Flex or similar Adobe platform?

Tags: apache-flex, api, desire2learn

I'm new to Flex, not new to web services, but definitely not sure how to get started with authenticating as a user against the Desire2Learn API within the Flex platform.

Some examples would really help, and maybe promote some of the great tablet apps that could get developed. Are there any public samples out there?  If not with Flex, then similar platforms?

Looking mostly here: http://code.google.com/p/desire2learn-valence/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no samples provided by Desire2Learn at this point. However, the source code for other platforms are posted. So you could take something like the [c# code](http://code.google.com/p/desire2learn-valence/source/browse/#svn/trunk/LearningFrameworkAPI/clientplatforms/dotnetsdk%253Fstate%253Dclosed) and combine that with the wiki docs in order to move it into flash/flex. (Also, javascript samples should be coming down the pipe)

If you create anything please feel free to contribute back to the project site.

Comment: There are now samples in php, java, javascript and C#.